# Error compiling ruby 1.9.3 using rvm, homebrew, or macports

Tags: ruby, bash, openssl, rvm, osx-lion

I've tried installing ruby 1.9.3 using rvm, using homebrew, and using macports and all seem to fail part way through the compile.  I'm using Lion OSX.

Here is the log file of my most recent attempt using rvm

http://pastebin.com/AEiJbGzD

Any help would be appreciated.  It all started when I started getting openssl errors so tried uninstalling openssl and re-installing it.  Openssl installed with no issue but then I couldn't get ruby re-installed.

Thanks

Comment: Do you, by any chance, have XCode 4.2 installed?

Comment: So your issue is likely because Apple decided to make `clang` the default compiler, whereas pretty much everything else kind of expects `gcc`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was able to install Ruby 1.9.3 on Lion and Xcode 4.2 using rvm with the `--with-gcc=clang` flag:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I prefer to use clang over GCC. The more of us that use it, the more first-class support it'll receive from the community.

Comment: Nice and easy! I also think using clang is a good idea. Also, the compiles should go faster and the code produced should run faster.

Answer (score 8):

You should install OSX GCC installer:
[GitHub - OSX GCC Installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer)

After installation you run:

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.3
```

And it should work.

Or you can change permanently:

```
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
rvm install 1.9.3
```

Xcode 4.2 doesn't install non-LLVM gcc anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem after reinstall mountain lion (clean install) and after install XCode 5 DP... I have followed the steps and installed Command Line Tools from Xcode/Preferences... and had having the same problem.

I have been checking https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?=command%20line%20tools and installed "Command Line Tools (OS X Mountain Lion) for Xcode - April 2013" after that, everything works fine.

Regards